# I/O in C: Reading integers and finding characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to come up with examples of IO in C. So I'm looking at the UVA for ACM ICPC input examples. I came across [this exercise](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=5&page=show_problem&problem=279). I figured it was ok, so I coded this:

```
  while(fgets(tmp,MAX,stdin)!=NULL){
    sscanf(tmp,"%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf ("num1: %d, num2: %d\n",x,y);
  }
```

for this input

```
12   5
    10     A
12 34
  123   456
  1    2
  10   2
```

Problem is... they accept a character (in this case `A`)... How do I check for that? I **do** need that A.

Comment: `scanf` tells you how many reads were successful. If you ignore that value, you are at risk of accessing junk (see [this example](http://ideone.com/l1wNaY)).

Comment: The question is not very clear - do you want to read `A`, or ignore that line?

Comment: 'A' is meant 0xA base 11 over. 
So those what read as a string rather than read as an int is good.

Comment: since the exercise is about reading integer values in an unspecified base, reading them as base 10 is probably not the way to go - you probably want to stick to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both items can be of any base, just read the 2 items as string (use `%s` in [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of functions) and store them into 2 arrays, then use `strtol` (and related functions such as [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), [`strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul), ...) to convert to different bases to test for equality.